# Can FaceTime be used within an app in ios5?

Tags: iphone, ios5

Have an app idea that I'd like to make using FaceTime. Can this application layer though be implemented in a 3rd party app or does it only run as FaceTime?

Answer (score 0):

Apple did mention that FaceTime would be an open standard but so far they have not released an API so the answer is no. It's a shame because there are some really cool things which could potentially be done if Apple decided to open it up.

Answer (score 0):

You can initiate a FaceTime call like this, but it won't be in app.

```
NSURL *facetimeURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"facetime://15555555555"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:facetimeURL];
```